# How to identify different authors in same pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-blame

I have one pull request with commits from different authors.

How can I identify inside Bitbucket diff view, which person made which change so I can tag them to review their respective modification?

Right know i need to open each file individually in another window and toogle the annotate function (old blame button). It's a very onerous process

Comment: In GitHub, you can do a review per commit. Isn't it possible in Bitbucket, too?

Comment: The number of commits will be very large and very often doesn't have the functionality in it. It might be an option but in this case would be better to each developer to make individual pull request of their working branch, containing a set of commits.